# Converting a String to Java Date in ISO 8601 date-time format

Tags: java, date

I am trying to convert a string into an ISO 8601 date-time format. Currently, this code

`String s1 = "2001-05-03T00:00:00+00:00";
Date firstAvailableDateTime = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX").parse(s1);`

gives me this result

`2001-05-03T00:00:00.000+0000`

However, this output is missing a colon in the timezone. The desired output is:

`2001-05-03T00:00:00.000+00:00`

According to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html, using "XXX" for the timezone should output a colon in the final date but it does not for me.

What am I missing?

I've looked at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso-8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date) but do not want to use Joda-Time since it may cause complications in the future moving between two date types.

Comment: `Date` does not have an internally assignable format.

Comment: Does that mean that I can't get a colon included in that date then?

Comment: Are you on Java 8? Can you use LocalDateTime?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I'm on Java 8 and can use LocalDateTime. Right now I have `DateTimeFormatter dtf =  DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX"); 
LocalDateTime lastAvailableDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("2011-05-03T00:00:00+00:00", dtf);` 
but the output comes out to just `"2011-05-03T00:00:00"`. So now there isnt even a timezone listed.

Comment: You need to use ZonedDateTime, not LocalDateTime.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Yup that worked. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. `OffsetDateTime` is the best fit when the string has an offset in is (`+00:00`) and no time zone (like Asia/Kolkata or Mountain Time).

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas As Ole V.V. commented, `ZonedDateTime` class is for values with a time zone (a history of past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region), while `OffsetDateTime` is appropriate for mere offset-from-UTC (simply a number of hours-minutes-seconds).

Comment: Without knowing the full use case I cannot recommend one or the other and ZonedDateTime is more broadly applicable, hence why I suggested it and why I have no regrets in doing so.

Comment: I’m a little bit confused because I cannot reproduce. From your code I get an old-fashioned `java.util.Date` object of `Thu May 03 02:00:00 CEST 2001`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
OffsetDateTime.parse( "2001-05-03T00:00:00+00:00" )
```

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

Never use `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date`, `Calendar`, etc. These terrible classes were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes.

## ISO 8601

> trying to convert a string into an ISO 8601 date-time format
>
> `String s1 = "2001-05-03T00:00:00+00:00"`

Your Question is quite confused.  Your input string *is* in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. The `T` in the middle separates the year-month-day from the hour-minute-second, and the `+00:00` at the end indicates an offset-from-UTC of zero hours and zero minutes, that is, UTC itself. All standard, all proper.

Perhaps you are conflating strings representing date-time values and date-time objects containing date-time values. A date-time object has no “format”; it has its own internally-defined representation of a date-time value. Only text has a format. A date-time class can parse a formatted string as input, and a date-time class can generate a formatted sting as output, but within the date-time there is no format at all.

### `OffsetDateTime`

The *java.time* classes use the ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating strings representing date-time values. So no need to specify a formatting pattern for such inputs.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2001-05-03T00:00:00+00:00" ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/u8CVvO).

> odt.toString(): 2001-05-03T00:00Z

### `Z`

There is a common abbreviation for an offset of zero: a simple `Z` letter, meaning UTC, and pronounced “Zulu”. Example: `2019-02-26T00:44:28Z`

The `Z` is quite commonly used. But if for some reason you prefer the numeric `+00:00`, use [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) options.

### COLON character

By the way, you mentioned the COLON character omitted from the offset: `+0000`. That is actually tolerated by the ISO 8601 standard. But I do not advise it. I have seen libraries and systems break on such inputs. Best to use full-length, hours *and* minutes, padding zeros, and the colon character: `+00:00` rather than `+0000`, and `-07:00` rather than `-7`.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

The solution that was found ended up being to use ZonedDateTime along with a DateTimeFormatter.

`DateTimeFormatter dtf =  DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME;
ZonedDateTime lastAvailableDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse("2011-05-03T00:00:00+05:00", dtf);`

The output from this code is:

`2011-05-03T00:00:00+05:00`

Comment: Still better and simpler: `OffsetDateTime lastAvailableDateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse("2011-05-03T00:00:00+05:00");`. No need for any explicit formatter.

Comment: `ZonedDateTime` class is for values with a time zone. When working with a mere offset-from-UTC rather than a time zone, use `OffsetDateTime`.